# SQL - Subquery returned more than 1 value. How to Fix?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

-- Using orders, customers, employees, and order details tables, select the Order Id, the Order Date,
-- the customer company name, the employee last name, and the total amount paid (including freight, but ignoring discount) for each order

I feel like I'm very close with my answer, but I keep running into this one error. I'm new to databases so I assume I'm overlooking something simple. I've looked at other pages with the same error and nothing really made sense to me.

The subquery works by itself but when I throw it into the rest of the query I get this error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here is my query thus far:

```
Select (Select (Sum(UnitPrice * Quantity) + Freight) as AmountPaid
    From [Order Details], Orders
    Group By [Order Details].OrderID, Freight), 
    OrderDate, [Order Details].OrderID, CompanyName, LastName 
From [Order Details], Customers, Employees
Inner Join Orders ON OrderID=Orders.OrderID
```

Comment: To use subquery in the "select" part, it can only return one row and one column. If you expect multiple rows, use join.

Comment: You are not very close with your answer.  Your joins in the outer query are all wrong.  The joins in the subquery are all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
(Sum(UnitPrice * Quantity) + Freight)
```

To

```
Sum((UnitPrice * Quantity) + Freight)
```

Comment: The freight is only added one time to each order after the sum of all the products in that order is calculated, not each time for every entry, as the orderID is specific to each shipment, not each product.

Answer (score 0):

Remove inner join clause.

Add where condition at the end something like below:

where table1.a = table2.a and table2.x = table3.y

See how table relationships are defined.